# Microsoft Graph API Download File content return Unauthorized 401

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to download a file from SharePoint Online using an "app only" token. I can obtain file info using this url

```
https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drives/{driveId}/list/items/{itemId}/driveItem
```

But when I try to download the file with this url

```
https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drives/{driveId}/list/items/{itemId}/driveItem/content
```

I get the following error

```
403 FORBIDDEN

Content-Length →13
Content-Type →text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date →Fri, 13 Apr 2018 08:47:12 GMT
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices →16.0.0.7604
P3P →CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
SPIisLatency →2
SPRequestDuration →53
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp →1; RequireReadOnly
X-MSDAVEXT_Error →917656; Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically.
X-MSEdge-Ref →Ref A: B9E0C567B0CC4E60AEE93EEB8DC06AF1 Ref B: VIEEDGE0813 Ref C: 2018-04-13T08:47:12Z
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
X-SharePointHealthScore →0
```

what is wrong?

it seems that internally it generates a download link (.../_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=...) that works with username / pwd token, but does not work with "app only" token

I have another office 365 subscription that works with "app only" token. The other subscription have a custom domain, but I can not see other configuration differences (both have LegacyAuthProtocolsEnabled property set to true, same sharing options...)

**EDIT:** It seems that the example I was testing on friday now works!!

Comment: Which scopes are you requesting?

Comment: We're sending content requests for graph api with app-only tokens and get 403, this is really bad. started few days ago

Answer (score 1):

This bug appeared wednesday last week, and is spreading to more and more of our tenants. It appears that temporary tokens generated by the Graph API/Sharepoint API are invalid. This affects:

- Chunked file upload, as you receice an url to upload to with a temporary token
- @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl as it contains a temporary token
- Content download, as it uses the excact same url as @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl

Please fix this ASAP, as my application is cripled and the customers are angry

I created a post here too, but no response: [Temporary tokens issued by graph api is invalid since wednesday](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e8799116-bb04-4e6c-8912-9000b40be975/temporary-tokens-issued-by-graph-api-is-invalid-since-yesterday-please-fix-asap?forum=Office365forDevelopers#e8799116-bb04-4e6c-8912-9000b40be975)

Also this bug appeared wednesday: [Unable to set fileSystemInfo.lastModifiedDateTime on files on Sharepoint Online for some users since wednesday](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ca9b6200-d62e-4779-ac27-682dc91fea62/unable-to-set-filesysteminfolastmodifieddatetime-on-files-on-sharepoint-online-for-some-users-since?forum=Office365forDevelopers)

Did you find anything on this [Mark LeFleur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105518/marc-lafleur)?

Comment: This has started again. Please fix ASAP

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl` property obtained from the  `/v1.0/me/drive/list/items/x/driveItem` response to get an app-only url to the file.
A GET request wil allow you to download the file.

See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/driveitem#instance-attributes

Comment: Hi Robin. I try to download file with the url from `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl`property and it works when I call  `/v1.0/me/drive/list/items/x/driveItem` with user/pwd token. When I use "app only" It does not work (403 FORBIDDEN with `X-MSDAVEXT_Error →917656; Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically.`)

Answer (score 0):

I have executed the same example that initially failed and now works, at least in the two tenants that I have.

I have not changed any configuration or source code, so it seems that it was a temporary problem that has been fixed.

Comment: This was caused by the activation of a new feature, which has since been disabled. You can read the later comments on this GitHub issue if you'd like a little more detail: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/528

Comment: [Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3570009/brad) Could you please fix this again ASAP?