# Resumable uploads support with app tokens (without a user)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Resumable uploads are giving me 403 errors with the PUT requests after creating the upload session.

I've used app level tokens for resumable uploads recently and they worked fine. I previously tried them months ago and they were not working and I remember something about them not being supported.

I don't find that text that states that in the documentation. Are they supported or is there another issue?

Thanks

Comment: This is a bug that started wednesday. See here: [Microsoft Graph API Download File content return Unauthorized 401
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813381/microsoft-graph-api-download-file-content-return-unauthorized-401/49850647#49850647)

Comment: @BoKDamgaard I am glad I am not alone, were you using app tokens ? because tokens on behalf of a user are working

Comment: Yes, I'm using app tokens

Answer (score 1):

We tracked down the issue to a new feature that was recently enabled and shut it off. The app-only scenarios should now be working as expected so please let us know if you continue to see issues.