# Teams Tab API access to Sharepoint FIle Contents causing 405 on OPTIONS call

Tags: microsoft-teams

- In Microsoft Teams, I have crated an App that lists files of a certain type in a Tab
- The use case is that the contents of the file need to be read by my Javascript
- the Javascript in the Tab *already successfully* gets an ID Token and Access Token (via ADAL)
- this code *already successfully* lists the DriveItems in the group the current logged in user can see 
  via `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/${groupId}/drive/root/search(q='{pdf}')`;`
- when I attempt to GET the DriveItem via
  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/${groupId}/drive/items/${itemId}/content`

  - where the `itemId` is returned from the first call
  - I successfully see the HTTP 302 from the `https://graph.microsoft.com` endpoint redirecting to `https://<thesharepointsite>.sharepoint.com/<etc>`
- Axios (and the Microsoft Graph Javascript API) are successfully traversing to the redirect
- Postman, with the same `https://graph...` URL with the AccessToken successfully downloads the binary content from the 302 redirect (so it is not an Auth issue)

**PROBLEM**

- in Microsoft Teams, inside my Tab, the browser (built inside of the Teams desktop app) HTTP calls to `https://<thesharepointside>.sharepoint.com` respond with a 405 error on the OPTIONS call
- usually this means there is a CORS issue, and so the solution is to add the domain to the `validDomains` of the app

**Attempted Solution**

- the Manifest has the following entries in validDomains

```js
"validDomains": [
       ...

        "*.sharepoint.com",
        "graph.microsoft.com",
        "login.microsoftonline.com"
    ]
```

- manually add the full domain the the Teams App's Manifest
- use the suggested "{teamsitedomain}" as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#validdomains
- *.sharepoint.com as per above
- use the Microsoft Graph Javascript APIs

In all instances, I get 405 on the OPTIONS call

No file download from within the Tab within Microsoft Teams.

*Suggestions?*

Answer (score 1):

*THIS MAY* answer your question in the future

- my code now does a `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/${groupId}/drive/items/${itemId}`
- this is an *Instance* of `DriveItem` and returns a property on the JSON response:
  `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl`
- as per [Microsoft Graph API Download File content return Unauthorized 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813381/microsoft-graph-api-download-file-content-return-unauthorized-401) this is a short-lived URL you can traverse *without* Auth headers
- the content of my file was returned successfully (no CORS issue)
- I can now download the contents of the `DriveItem` within a Tab
- I hope this helps someone